# How to access each block of the image to perform wavelet transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an MRI image 
[image: Brain] .

I want to divide 256x256 size of this image into 5-by-5 overlapping blocks. Each of these blocks would then be further processed for wavelet transform and then GLCM texture feature extraction. Something like this 
[image: visual].

I have written the function for the transformation and feature extraction but couldn't access each block of the image to pass through the function. 
I know that MATLAB has blockproc function to divide image into blocks and process each block for some function. I wrote like this

```
     B=blockproc(LX,[16 16],WaveletT);
```

where WaveleT is a function like:

```
    function FV= WaveletT 
    level = 1;      
    [c,s] = wavedec2(' ',level,'haar');
    [chd1,cvd1,cdd1] = detcoef2('all',c,s,level);
    sizechd1=size(chd1);
    sizecvd1=size(cvd1);
    sizecdd1=size(cdd1);
    A=appcoef2(c,s,'haar');
    sizeA=size(A);
    mA=mean2(A);
    sdA=std2(A);
    sdD=std2(cdd1);
    sdH=std2(chd1);
    sdV=std2(cvd1);
    FV=[mA,sdA,sdD,sdH,sdV];

    end
```

What should I pass as an image to 'wavedec' function and what would 'B' will store? I know I am doing something wrong in 'blockproc', so please help by providing a solution.

Comment: Consider placing your edit as an actual answer and mark it as accepted.  I spent a few minutes looking through your question only to realize that you actually solved it.  To prevent others from wasting their time, add an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found it on my own. So adding it here if anyone else might like to know.

```
    B=im2col(X,[5 5],'sliding'); %this would create 25*63504 matrix
    [m, n]=size(B);
    C=reshape(B(:,i),[5 5]); %5-by-5 block of above image where i=1:63504
```

This C will be passed in 'wavedec' function.( see WaveletT function above).
So instead of using 'blockproc', 'im2col' did the needed.